# Sort the rows data for CSV or Excel export using MUI DataGrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, export, mui-x-data-grid

How to sort the row data for exporting to CSV or Excel using the MUI DataGrid?

Below is my code sample for the `toolbar`.

```
      slots={{
        noRowsOverlay: NoDataComponent,
        noResultsOverlay: NoDataComponent,
        toolbar: (
          <GridToolbarExport
            sx={{
              borderRadius: 24
            }}
            variant='contained'
            size='medium'
            disabled={loading || clients.items?.length === 0}
            printOptions={{
              disableToolbarButton: true
            }}
            csvOptions={{
              allColumns: false,
              fields: [
                'createdDateTime',
                'partnerId',
                'company',
                'referenceNumber',
                'fullname',
                'status',
                'currencyType',
                'lastCreditMonitoringDate',
                'approvedLine',
                'availableLine',
                'utilisedLine',
                'nextRenewalDate',
                'creditlineStatus',
                'newShadowLimitDecision',
                'decision',
                // 'dateOfShadowLimitChange',
                'notes',
                'authorizedby'
              ],
              fileName: `Partner_customer_Report_${new Date().getTime()}`
            }}
          />
        ),
        loadingOverlay: () => LoadingSkeleton(pageSize)
      }}
```

I have tried the diifferent options for the CSV exports as described in the [MUI DatGrid site.](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/grid-csv-export-options/)

I think using the `getRowsToExport` prop can be helpful to achieve the result, But I don't know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve the result using the `getRowsToExport` prop, just as I have shown below.

```
  slots={{
    noRowsOverlay: NoDataComponent,
    noResultsOverlay: NoDataComponent,
    toolbar: (
      <GridToolbarExport
        sx={{
          borderRadius: 24
        }}
        variant='contained'
        size='medium'
        disabled={loading || clients.items?.length === 0}
        printOptions={{
          disableToolbarButton: true
        }}
        csvOptions={{
          allColumns: false,
          fields: [
            'createdDateTime',
            'partnerId',
            'company',
            'referenceNumber',
            'fullname',
            'status',
            'currencyType',
            'lastCreditMonitoringDate',
            'approvedLine',
            'availableLine',
            'utilisedLine',
            'nextRenewalDate',
            'creditlineStatus',
            'newShadowLimitDecision',
            'decision',
            'notes',
            'authorizedby'
          ],
          fileName: `Partner_customer_Report_${new Date().getTime()}`,
          getRowsToExport: (params: GridCsvGetRowsToExportParams) => {
            let response = [] as GridRowId[];

            if (params.apiRef.current) {
              params.apiRef.current.setSortModel([{ field: 'referenceNumber', sort: 'asc' }]);
              response = params.apiRef.current.getSortedRowIds();
            }

            return response;
          }
        }}
      />
    ),
    loadingOverlay: () => LoadingSkeleton(pageSize)
  }}
```

Explanation:

- First, we can sort the rows based on the required column and order sequence by passing the sorted data to the `setSortModel` function to arrange the data accordingly.
- After this sorting operation, we simply return the list of sorted row IDs using the `getSortedRowIds` function. This prop should return the data in the form of `GridRowId[]`.

Therefore, the `getRowsToExport` should be structured as follows.

```
  getRowsToExport: (params: GridCsvGetRowsToExportParams) => {
            let response = [] as GridRowId[];

            if (params.apiRef.current) {
              params.apiRef.current.setSortModel([{ field: 'referenceNumber', sort: 'asc' }]);
              response = params.apiRef.current.getSortedRowIds();
            }

            return response;
          }
```

I hope this helps you. Thanks.